# Xcode 14 error Build input file cannot be found

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo

I’m unable to create app variants using Xcode 14. I followed the instructions provided on the doc link. However, when I tried to build the app, the following error appeared:

> Build input file cannot be found:
> /Users/ma/Documents/dev/AppName/mobile/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/Pods-AppName/ExpoModulesProvider.swift'. Did you forget to
> declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule
> which produces it?

I tried cleaning the build and deleting the derived data, but unfortunately, none of those worked

Has anyone faced this problem ?

Thanks in advance